Como puedo acceder al llamar a Bedrock?
Estoy creando un Agente en Bedrock dentro de AWS, ya cree una base de conocimiento y si me responde, pero el problema que tengo es cuando creo el agente, lo conecto a la base de conocimiento y realizo una pregunta me responde "Access denied when calling Bedrock. Check your request permissions and retry the request.".
Ya revise mis permisos y estan de acuerdo a la documentación.
Seguí los pasos de esta liga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77674389/amazon-bedrock-agent-access-denied-when-calling-bedrock-check-your-request-pe pero no resolvieron este problema.

Cree un Rol con los siguientes permisos


Asigne mi rol a mi agente



No funciono, también probé con políticas y tampoco

En todos los casos tuve la misma respuesta

Alguien me puede ayudar? estoy trabajando con Región Oregón
